# Is it possible to exclude objects from rendering in Post-Processing Volume in Unity HDRP/URP?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in Unity and I recently switched to the new 2022 LTS version of Unity so I can use the HDRP water, but it needs a volume called "Sky and Fog Global Volume" in order to work. This volume adds various things, including volumetric lights. The volumetric lights glitch out my flashlight and cause a fast flickering effect that looks really buggy and bad, I was wondering if there is a way to exclude GameObjects from getting rendered with the post-processing volume. Also, I am using the URP and HDRP versions of volumes, not the ones that are used on the Built-in Render Pipeline. If I was using the Built-in Render Pipeline version of the post-processing, this would all be solved and I would easily be able to exclude objects from getting rendered with the post-processing. The water only needs one of the volume overrides called the "Water Rendering" to render, but I do not want to get rid of the volumetric override because it makes the water look a lot better than without. Also, the volumetric lights are just from a fog override with the Volumetric fog setting enabled. You probably already guessed but the Volume is global and I want to keep it that way.

I tried using the layer matrix but I was pretty sure I was in the wrong place. I made a layer called "FogVolumeIgnore" and thought it would be useful later so that I could use it in some code maybe to not render volumes on. I think that the way that the post-processing works for the HDRP and URP Volumes is different from the Built-in Render Pipeline Post Processing Volume, I am pretty sure that the Built-in Render Pipeline way of rendering it is by applying the effects to the object whereas the HDRP and URP Volumes apply most the effects straight to all the cameras in the scene. I couldn't find anywhere in the volume settings that allowed me to stop rendering the effects on certain GameObjects because of this. I couldn't find anything related to this on the Unity Documentation, and all the guides I found online were for the Built-in Render Pipeline only, is it even possible to exclude GameObjects with the HDRP/URP Volumes?

EDIT:

This glitch miraculously disappeared after a few weeks, I have no clue to what fixed it, but it might be from updating to the newset HDRP version that fixed the bug, which is what I guess solved it. I didn't mess with any of the settings to fix it either. I wish I could explain why this happened so that anyone else with this glitch wouldn't have been led to a dead end, but I do have a few guesses to why it happened. I think that this glitch is exclusive to the Unity 2022 LTS version and it also might be patched in newer HDRP versions. The glitch might be with certain parameters of the fog volume and it might be because the light is at the same coordinates as the camera, and it might be the perspective of the fog layering because it has a really long range and the flickering could be from the light moving. But other than that I really wish I had a solid answer and sorry if anyone else has this same error, just remember to update your HDRP version and get the newest patch for the Unity 2022 LTS, good luck!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.